# how to do a validation in visualforce page for a filed and display an alert message?

Tags: visualforce, community, salesforce1-app, visualforce-component

Hi i have a visualforce page which checks whether the user has entered his name email and phone number. if he has entered then it should call the action in the controller extension?

Have to add validation in this page.

adding the code

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="zqu__Quote__c" extensions="QuoteControllerLightning" action="{!autoRun}">  
<apex:sectionHeader title="Open DocuSign Envelope Page and Pop Page"/>   
<apex:outputPanel > You tried calling the an Apex Controller from a button.  If you see this page, something went wrong. Print this page and send the error to HDNotifier.  
</apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Right now we have done it without validation.

Comment: then you can simply have a if..else block before that action in controller, If values are enter call that action else, throw the exception for those values Or you can also have try,catch block.